# How to transform MultiLineString produced in python to R object?

Tags: python, r, shapely, reticulate

I'm integrating a python function in R code using the  `reticulate`  package, the original output in python is MultiLineString.
Class of output in Rstudio is :

```
> class(result)
[1] "centerline.geometry.Centerline"                   "shapely.geometry.multilinestring.MultiLineString"
[3] "shapely.geometry.base.BaseMultipartGeometry"      "shapely.geometry.base.BaseGeometry"              
[5] "python.builtin.object"

> typeof(result)
[1] "environment"
```

Output in Rstudio :

```
> result
MULTILINESTRING ((188.84310143 -25.44115933212567, 189.0883871453183 -25.39224242194983),
(189.34310143 -25.40412148482432, 189.0883871453183 -25.39224242194983))
```

I'm new to python, is there any way to transfer the output in python or R, so I can use it to make Spatiallines or SF object?

Comment: I guess you transfer it using WKB or [WKT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text_representation_of_geometry) representation (which your output currently is). Does the information available in this [comment on GitHub](https://github.com/rstudio/reticulate/issues/338#issuecomment-461198668) (or elsewhere on the thread) helps ?

Comment: It is helpful, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#output of python function in R 
> class(result)
[1] "centerline.geometry.Centerline"                   "shapely.geometry.multilinestring.MultiLineString"
[3] "shapely.geometry.base.BaseMultipartGeometry"      "shapely.geometry.base.BaseGeometry"              
[5] "python.builtin.object"

> typeof(result)
[1] "environment"

#Convert from Python to R object 
processed <- reticulate::py_to_r(result)

#change type from environment to character 
result_2<-type.convert(processed,as.is = TRUE)

#read WKT and construct SpatialLines
x<-readWKT(result_2)


> x
class       : SpatialLines 
features    : 1 
extent      : 187.6103, 191.6382, -25.8519, -24.55464  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs         : NA
```

Comment: The `rgeos::read_wkt()` can read the original centerline file. So there is no need to convert from python to r. In the case of using `centerline` library (https://centerline.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) you can convert to `SpatialLines` class as follows `x <- rgeos::readWKT(result)`